# What happened to Miss Dunya's skin when she died?

Tags: magi

What happened to Miss Dunya's skin when she died? (Shown in the animated .GIF below)

[image: Miss Dunya's skin changing as she dies]

For reference, it occurred in Episode 2 of Magi - The Kingdom of Magic around 16:17.

Answer (score 1):

She turned into metal coal after she died. This happened due to the side effect of turning into a black djinn.

[The Magi wikia](http://magi.wikia.com/wiki/Dunya_Musta%27sim) gives you more information on her.